# UiSplitViewController doesn't autorotate

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, autorotate

I have recently run into a problem.  My iPad app is somehow preventing the iPad from auto-rotating.  My app loads a UISplitView with both of the view controllers returning YES for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:.  I have set up my info.plist to include the "Supported interface orientations" key with all four orientations.  When I run the app, however, rotating the device does not rotate the splitView (even though I am receiving UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification).  In addition, when I exit my app in a different orientation that it started in the iPad home screen doesn't autorotate to the correct view until I rotate it again without my app running....  Any Ideas would be much appreciated....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UISplitViewController` is one of the most temperamental view controller subclasses I've ever had to use. In order for it to work "perfectly", it **must** exist as a single root view in your application's window. You can, however, get around this with some trickery -- in my case, I needed a `UITabBarController` with at least two distinct `UISplitViewController`s as view controllers -- but then you have to take care of weird cases involving rotation and `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` callbacks not firing.

Here's hoping that Apple makes `UISplitViewController` more compatible with other `UIKit` components in the future...

Comment: You can get around it with trickery you say...  What trickery?  You tease!

Comment: What it came down to was just forwarding appropriate rotation methods manually. Logging a bunch of stuff to see what methods were and we're not being called. Then I just compensated in my root view controller subclass by making sure the child view controllers got the right methods fired, resized their views, etc.

Comment: I am having the same problem right now of having my SplitViewController's, which are tabs under a TabBarController, act erratic, so it's glad to know it's not just me! Thanks for that comfort at least!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem with two subordinate UINavigationControllers. In my case the rotation started working once I overrode shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in the left controller to always return 'YES'.

Comment: Both the masterView and the detailView need to support YES for whatever orientation you are trying to rotate to. If either one doesn't return YES, it won't rotate. I missed this subtle detail, my masterView only supported portrait. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work fine - provided BOTH children of the `UISplitViewController` implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

I.e if you have something like:

```
        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];

       self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

to define the `rootViewController` of your `NSApplication` 
then both `MasterViewController` and `DetailViewController` should implement:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

as to ensure that rotation works.

Answer (score 1):

Is your UISplitViewController set as your root view controller?  If not, that may be the cause of your problem.  I was having a similar issue - the status bar would rotate but my detail and master views would stay in place.  I rearranged the views so that the UISplitViewController was the root and then my 'main menu' was presented as a modal view controller on top of the split view, and it made the rotation problem go away.

According to the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html), "The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the root view of your application window."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your first Problem is, that the UISplitView prevents you from autorotating. Try to use a Subclass of Splitview instead that enbales autorotating:

```
@implementation SplitViewControllerRotating
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    NSLog(@"SplitViewControllerRotating shouldAutorotate");
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Your second problem sounds weird. You said after exiting your app you have to rotate, so that your iPad recognizes interface-orientation. Cant help you with that.

Comment: I gave it a shot... It didn't work... Isn't the purpose of the UISplitView to autorotate anyway?

Comment: Does anyone know a solution on iOS 9? Answers answered above are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now.  The reason was that I had accidentally added *another* view to the window in addition to UISplitViewController's view.  Removing the extra view made it work.